# What happened to the GUI for experimenting with OpenCV?

Tags: user-interface, opencv, image-processing, code-generation

There used to be a gui toolkit for experimenting with OpenCV image processing pipelines including code generation. I think it started with an "h". What is it called, and what happened to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you refer to [Harpia](http://s2i.das.ufsc.br/harpia/en/home.html). It's available in Ubuntu applications if you enter OpenCV in SW repository (Ubuntu Software Center) search box

Comment: That's the one. Unfortunately it is only available for 2-Ubuntus-Ago and is unstable (many operations appear not to work) on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in Ubuntu 10.10 (now using 11.10) but was disappointed in the end. That was good just as an introductory step.

Answer (score 2):

I think I saw in the past a nice tool to test opencv functions, not so sure about the code generation.

Now i found this one, it looks decent:

http://code.google.com/p/piaf/

This one looks nice but experimental:

http://siggiorn.com/videopipe/

And these, but look poor and ancient:

http://code.google.com/p/cvpreprocessor/

http://code.google.com/p/open-rtvision/

**EDIT:**

This one is dedicated to feature detecting module:

http://introlab.github.io/find-object/

Answer (score 1):

This is called HighGUI. You can find many docs in the web. Here's one of them: [Load and Display an Image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not it. The tool I remember had a drag-and-drop workspace that was used to rearrange and connect image processing elements without coding or compiling.

Comment: @joeforker I'm not sure but maybe you're talking about [this plugin](http://vvvv.org/contribution/opencv-plugin-(alpha))?